# Subtracting time in different formats in PHP

Tags: time, php

Hi I'd like to take an hour off of a time stored in my DB and output it.

`$row['expiration_abs_date'] = '2012-11-05 16:03:08'`

Here's what I have:

```
date("M-j H:i \P\S\T",strtotime($row['expiration_abs_date']))
```

My best guess that doesn't work:

```
date("M-j H:i \P\S\T",strtotime($row['expiration_abs_date']) - strtotime(1 hour))
```

Comment: try `strtotime($row['expiration_abs_date']) - 3600`

Comment: You could do it in the query. Here's a MySQL snippet:
`select date_add('2012-11-05 16:03:08', INTERVAL -1 HOUR)`

Comment: `SELECT timefield - INTERVAL 1 HOUR` in mysql will do it for you without having to use multiple format conversions/roundtrips between time<->string values in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date("M-j H:i \P\S\T",strtotime($row['expiration_abs_date'])-3600)
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime($row['expiration_abs_date'].' -1 hour')`